# How should I uninstall/remove Adobe Shockwave Flash in elementary OS?

Tags: firefox

I can disable it in my Firefox browser, but how to delete it completely?

Answer (score 1):

Open synaptic package manager -> find `flashplugin-installer` -> Mark for comeplete removal -> Apply.